# Flutter: Track build time programatically (not in Flutter DevTools)

Tags: flutter, debugging, analysis

Is there any way to programmatically measure the build time for `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`?

I want to emphasize that I know about Flutter's feature-rich DevTools. However, I would like to measure it for complex widgets and report it in release mode.

Comment: tried https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FrameTiming-class.html?

Comment: @pskink According to the available fields, it does not seem like that I can be specific about certain widgets. Yes, it gives me a `buildDuration` - but this sums up the entire frame, not the widget (at least if I understood that correctly). Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like that this won't do the trick.